# Vue: Event Object Not Accessible

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to emit a standard `JavaScript` event (in addition to the Vue event), so I have the following code inside a Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="input"
      v-model.trim="value"
      :id="id"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :required="required"
      :readonly="readonly"
      autocomplete="off"
      @keyup="keyUp"
      @focus="focus"
      @click="click"
      @dblclick="dblclick"
      @change="change">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        change () {
            // Vanilla event
            let element = document.querySelector(`#${this.id}`);
            let event = new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false });

            element.dispatchEvent(event);

            // Vue event
            this.$emit('change');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

However, I get the following error in reference to the vanilla Event:

```
'Event' is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: `Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113`

Comment: What is the reasoning behind needing to fire the custom event? If you open your console, can you create the event manually?

Comment: What gives the error? The browser? Event is definitely available in that version of Chrome.

Comment: @AndrewWillis, the custom event is because I have a one-off listener at the top of the app handling specific events that Vue doesn't directly generate. Bert, it is Vue that is reporting the error.

Comment: Can we see the template for this?

Comment: @Bert Added the template.

Comment: Well, one thing I can see playing around with this is if you emit from the element itself, as you do, you will end up with an infinite loop. You have a change handler on the input element and you emit `change` from the element. I'm unable to replicate the Event error you are seeing though. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ayRqKr?editors=1010

Comment: Ah, nice catch. 

Answer (score -1):

It's a hunch, but I suspect this might be to do with order. Vue strips event listeners inside elements to which it attaches. Try attaching all your event listeners after you've created your vue. We have vue coexisting happily with existing javascript code, including event listeners. But we don't like it, and we're making good progress at getting rid of the old stuff. (Do you really need to?)

Comment: I am adding the new listener after the component is mounted so that should be in good shape. Unfortunately, I don't see another solution, so I think I'll have to figure this one out.